# PHP Apache conf issue

Tags: php, apache

My Apache install is having issues starting with PHP? The code below kills the start.

```
#PHP INSTALL START
PHPIniDir "C:\ws\php"
LoadModule php5_module "C:\ws\php\php5apache2_2.dll"
#PHP END
```

When I remove it, it starts fine. I really need PHP working, so I can get back to work.

Comment: try to use xampp, everything up and working: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

Comment: Did you try the thread-safe version or the non-thread-safe version of that dll? Try to switch between the two.

Comment: What is in the Apache error log?

Comment: Solved. Was using VC6 when I should have used VC9 thread-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are, that php5apache2_2.dll is missing, or incompatible with your version of Apache.

In any case, check your startup logs for the reason of failure.

Comment: Test Configuration just pops up and disappears like all is good. Where can I get a compatible Apache2.2 php5apache2_2.dll for Windows 7?

Comment: Solved it! I was using VC6 and I should have used VC9 Thread-Safe. Thanks.

Comment: @yanike, excellent!  I figured that was it, and was just about to post with that suggestion.  I had a similar problem awhile back.